# scala elasticsearch using high level rest java client: regexp and scroll

Tags: regex, scala, elasticsearch, rest-client, elasticsearch-java-api

I am using scala (2.12) to query the Elasticsearch (6.5) using the High level java rest client(6.5).

```
libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch" % "6.5.4"

libraryDependencies += "org.elasticsearch.client" % "elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client" % "6.5.4"
```

Basic query (matchQuery) and scroll works fine for me.

```
val credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider
    credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials("user", "password"))

val builder = RestClient.builder(new HttpHost("host", port, "https"))

builder.setHttpClientConfigCallback(new HttpClientConfigCallback() {
      override def customizeHttpClient(httpClientBuilder: HttpAsyncClientBuilder): HttpAsyncClientBuilder = httpClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider)
})

var client = new RestHighLevelClient(builder)

val scroll = new Scroll(TimeValue.timeValueMinutes(1L))

// Index
val searchRequest = new SearchRequest("index")

val searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder()

searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("name.field", "value"))

searchSourceBuilder.size(500)

searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder)

searchRequest.scroll(scroll)
var searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT)
var scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId
var searchHits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits

while (searchHits != null && searchHits.length > 0) {
      val scrollRequest = new SearchScrollRequest(scrollId)
      scrollRequest.scroll(scroll)
      searchResponse = client.scroll(scrollRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT)
      println(searchResponse.getHits.getHits.toList)
      scrollId = searchResponse.getScrollId
      searchHits = searchResponse.getHits.getHits

}
```

**Basically above query works as expected with all the data returned.**

Now, my case is *I need the regex* (and not mathQuery).

**So I just change that line; but it does not fetch anything now.**

```
searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.regexpQuery("name.field", "value"))
```

What am I missing here? How to use Regexp ?